# javascript new line split is splitting at every n char

Tags: javascript

i am using below code to split the data but unfortunately not able to achieve it.

i have tried below things

```
var lines = data. split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);

data string is "this is ended here
                another line "
```

what is happening is it is returing like below

```
this is e
ded herea
other li
e
```

actually it is splitting at every character "n" i am going crazy.. but not able to find out what is issue.

could anybody please share some light on it.

UPDATE -

i think something is wrong when i put it on godaddy hosting.. on my desktop it is working fine.. any idea?? This is server site javascript.

thank you

UPDATE - 20/08/13
Despite various try my server level javascript split did not work, so i moved server level javascript to client level... and everything is working fine...

Thank you everyone for answering this issue. here i can accept only one answer as correct.. though all the answers provided below are correct.

Comment: this is not your actual code, is it not

Comment: Paste the actual code, please.

Comment: var lines = data. split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);

Comment: above line is actual line.. no matter what data string have it is just splitting on every "n" occurrence..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex must be wrong and you have written

```
split(/\n\r|\r|n/);
```

or something instead of

```
split(/\n\r|\r|\n/);
```

Comment: Thank you Antti..for reply.. i think something is wrong when i put it on godaddy hosting.. on my desktop it is working fine.. any idea??

Comment: No, you need to use `/\r\n|\r|\n/` in that exact order, else it would split on `\r\n` twice.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me in Chrome and FF :

```
var data = "this is ended here \n another line ";
var lines = data.split(/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/g);
console.log(lines);
```

It writes :

```
["this is ended here ", " another line "]
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hTSpH/)

Comment: Hi Damien,
Thank you for reply... just to let you know that i am just tested this code on my desktop it works fine.. but not sure when i am putting it on godaddy it is not working.. i am using apache on my desktop as well godady.. do you have any clue..please..

Comment: Is this regex running at the server or the client side ?